# Getting browser deviceOrientation depending on device head

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, gyroscope

I'm using browser's deviceOrientation event through `Gyronorm.js` library. I'm only interested in the rotation around `x` axis (the direction the camera is looking when in landscape mode).

The problem I'm facing is that when rotation on `y` changes, `x` does too. For example, when holding the phone in landscape mode rotation around `x` axis is 0. From that point if I tilt the phone around the `y` axis so it turns into a positive angle, the rotation around `x` becomes -180.

What I want is something like a "local rotation" so rotation in `x` axis doesn't change when `y` and `z` does. Is there any way to achieve those values?

The image below explains the coordinate system that I'm refering to.
[image]